# robots.tx disallow all with crawl-delay

Tags: robots.txt

I would like to get information from a certain site, and checked to see if I were allowed to crawl it.  The robots.txt file had considerations for 15 different user agents and then for everyone else.  My confusion comes from the everyone else statement (which would include me).  It was

```
User-agent: *                  
Crawl-delay: 5
Disallow: /
Disallow: /sbe_2020/pdfs/
Disallow: /sbe/sbe_2020/2020_pdfs
Disallow: /newawardsearch/
Disallow: /ExportResultServlet*
```

If I read this correctly, the site is asking that no unauthorized user-agents crawl it.  However, the fact that they included a Crawl-delay seems odd.  If I'm not allowed to crawl it, why would there even be a crawl delay consideration?  And why would they need to include any specific directories at all?  Or, perhaps I've read the " Disallow: /" incorrectly?

Comment: Consider the fact that someone might not have known what they were doing …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this record would mean the same if it were reduced to this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

A bot matched by this record is not allowed to crawl anything on this host (having an unneeded `Crawl-delay` doesn’t change this).

Comment: Sorry about the delayed comment.  I decided that I'd write to the site and ask their techs if they'd permit me searching it.  I never got any reply.  So, as noted, this record could easily be reduced to what @unor notes here.